# Rails: One-to-One relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a **Rails project** and I am using namespacing for the models and controllers. That is the child models (`admin` and `student`) are put in a directory called `user` and the controllers are put in a directory called users.

I also have `admins_controller` and `students_controller` that use the `admin` model and the `student` model respectively. These controllers are namespaced using `users` directory.

I then have a `personal_info` model that contains more details about the `user`, such as gender, age, date of birth. The `personal_info` table has a one-to-one relationship with the `user` model.

**Here's my code**;

**Personal Info model**:

```
class PersonalInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_one :personal_info, class_name: 'PersonalInfo', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_info, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Admin model**:

```
class User::Admin < User
end
```

**Admin Controller**:

```
class Users::AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_admin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /admins
  # GET /admins.json
  def index
    @admins = User::Admin.all
  end

  # GET /admins/1
  # GET /admins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /admins/new
  def new
    @admin = User::Admin.new
    @admin.build_personal_info
  end

  # GET /admins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /admins
  # POST /admins.json
  def create
    @admin = User::Admin.new(admin_params)
    @admin.build_personal_info

    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_admin_path(@admin), notice: 'Admin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: users_admin_path(@admin) }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @admin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /admins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /admins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @admin.update(admin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to users_admin_path(@admin), notice: 'Admin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: users_admin_path(@admin) }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @admin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /admins/1
  # DELETE /admins/1.json
  def destroy
    @admin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_admins_url, notice: 'Admin was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_admin
    @admin = User::Admin.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def admin_params
    params.require(:user_admin).permit(
      :email, :password, :role_id, 
      personal_info_attributes: [ :id, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, 
                                   :gender, :dob, :address, :city, :state, 
                                   :country ]
    )
  end
end
```

**Routes**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :users do
    resources :admins
    resources :students
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**:

```
<% if @admin.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@admin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this admin from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @admin.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= fields_for :personal_info do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :last_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
</div>

<%= fields_for :personal_info do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :phone %>
    <%= form.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.text_field :password %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>
```

**new.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Editing Admin</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @admin, url: users_admins_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', admin: @admin, locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_admins_path %>
```

However, when I try to create a new `admin` or update an already existing `admin` after adding inputs to the displayed form no `Personal Info` data is saved on the database. They are all **nil**.

> PersonalInfo Load (0.3ms) SELECT "personal_infos".* FROM "personal_infos" WHERE "personal_infos"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["user_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]

> => #<PersonalInfo id: 2, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, phone: nil, gender: nil, dob: nil, address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, country: nil, user_id: 6, created_at: "2020-06-26 13:37:16", updated_at: "2020-06-26 13:37:16">

I have tried to get this resolved, but no luck yet. Any form of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should call your `fields_for` from admin form as:

```
<%= form.fields_for :personal_info do |form| %>
```

otherwise it sends these params independent from admin, rather than nested as you'd like.

fwiw, for better reading, I would consider rename your inner personal_info form variable to not clash with admin form variable. But that's just a suggestion. :)